# Undefined variable: category_name after 2.8.1 upgrade?

Tags: channel-entries, 2.8

I've run into a problem after updating from 2.7.3 to 2.8.1. I've got a couple pages that have this error (below).

I've also noticed, every time I have an "{exp:channel:entries} {/exp:channel:entries}" tag, the error is present. So if I repeated the tags 3 times, I'de have the error repeat 3 times.

Has anyone ran into this problem after upgrading?

```
Severity: Notice  
Message: Undefined variable: category_name
Filename: helpers/segment_helper.php
Line Number: 98
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the fix.
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20152

Edit system/expressionengine/helpers/segment_helper.php around line 97 to add this conditional above ee()->load->model(‘category_model’); so it looks like:

```
if (empty($category_name))
            {
                return '';
            }

            ee()->load->model('category_model');
```

Comment: This seems to happen if the reserved category word is anywhere in the URL. In my case I'd put 'c' as the category word, and it bonked out on any URL with 'c' in it afterwards.

Comment: This happens not only for upgraded EE CMSes, but also for fresh installs. Great answer, thank you!